# Develop/Compile a lib for an android project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, g++

I have some cpp files in a directory (10 cpp files and ten relatives .h files corresponding to 10 classes). 
I would like to create my own library with them (let call it libTest.a) in order to put it on an android project using NDK.

I have already :

- C++ code
- Create and configure the android project with NDK, so basically I have an Android.mk and a cpp file into the jni folder

I spent about 10 hours on the web trying to find someone who can explain how to compile its own lib.a

I found a lot about "how can I put a .a in an android project using ndk" but nothing about how to create a makefile, a config file or whatever in order to correctly compile and make a lib compatible with android.

The one who will give me some advices will made my day!

Thanks a lot

(My Android.mk below)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# static library info
LOCAL_MODULE := libTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../prebuild/libTest.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../prebuild/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../prebuild/include

LOCAL_MODULE    := mlaudioengine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mlaudioengine.cpp

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libTest


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Why do you want a `lib.a`? Are you sure you don't need a dynamically loaded library, i.e. an `.so` file?

Comment: Please  share your **Android.mk**

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot it. Yeah I said lib.a but it could be lib.so I think one or the other would not change to much isn't it ?

Comment: I thought that you did not have a prebuilt lib. Tried to replace `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` with `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`? And list the C++ files as LOCAL_SRC.

Comment: Wowww thank you ! it compiles now ! But I still can't include a file of my lib in the jni cpp file like #include <MyClassInLib.h>

Comment: Moreover, even if it compiles, I have these two line printed 4 times : Android NDK:   jni../prebuild/libTest.a    
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in jni/Android.mk for module Test